# Plotting scale for area chart when all values are positive

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to produce a chart that is mixed `area` and `line` chart.  Consider my dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([range(1, 4)] * 5, columns=list('ABC')).assign(B=lambda d: -d.B).cumsum()
```

And my chart

```
df.C.plot.area(stacked=False)
df.A.plot()
df.B.plot()
```

[image]

Notice that the negative series does not show up.
Now suppose I make one entry of series `C` a negative value

```
df.loc[3, 'C'] = -1
```

And plot again

```
df.C.plot.area(stacked=False)
df.A.plot()
df.B.plot()
```

[image]

This is what I expected.  However, I do have data for series `C` that is all one sign.  How do I plot it such that the scale isn't ruined for my other series?

---

### MCVE

```
# messed up
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([range(1, 4)] * 5, columns=list('ABC')).assign(B=lambda d: -d.B).cumsum()

df.C.plot.area(stacked=False)
df.A.plot()
df.B.plot()
```

---

```
# correct but I have to put false data
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([range(1, 4)] * 5, columns=list('ABC')).assign(B=lambda d: -d.B).cumsum()
df.loc[3, 'C'] = -1

df.C.plot.area(stacked=False)
df.A.plot()
df.B.plot()
```

Comment: If you would please provide a complete functioning code example, I could try to help you.  For example here you seem to have omitted some import statements that are necessary for it to run

Comment: All the code is there.  I'll put it all together.

Comment: Never mind, it was straightforward to figure out what import statements you were using

Comment: `plt.autoscale(True)`?

Comment: @Mr.T that did it.  Add the answer pls.

Comment: It seems that it should be doing that as the default.   Is there something in your code that turns it off?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know what.  You should be able to replicate the issue with the sample code.  If not, then it must be a versioning issue.

Comment: Area plots are "pinned" to 0 (just like bar plots), which makes them look nice without the additional 5% margin applied at the bottom. Here this hinders automatc scaling. However you may turn that on for the y axis, `plt.autoscale(axis="y")`.

Comment: Yep, of course,  Importance has it.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I was hoping that you will enlighten us about the reason for this behavior. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>I don't know, why this bug happens.</s>* But you can enforce [autoscale](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.autoscale.html). If you want to autoscale only one axis, you can specify it:

```
#not messed up anymore
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([range(1, 4)] * 5, columns=list('ABC')).assign(B=lambda d: -d.B).cumsum()

df.C.plot.area(stacked=False)
df.A.plot()
df.B.plot()

plt.autoscale(True, axis = "y")
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

*As @ImportanceOfBeingErnest points out in the comments, it is not a bug but the desired behavior for area plots, which unluckily collides with the line plot here.

Comment: [It's not a bug.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51488111/plotting-scale-for-area-chart-when-all-values-are-positive#comment89945632_51488111) Although one might argue that there could be a directive in the `plot` generation to undo the "pinning" in case of negative numbers. This seems like a very special case to me, so the user is left to do it himself. If there is a large demand for such feature, one can of course open a wishlist-issue on github about it.

Comment: Btw. to get the "original" look of an area plot back, one might in addition set `ax.set_margins(x=0)` in case that is desired.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that shows how to set the limits explicitly:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([range(1, 4)] * 5, columns=list('ABC')).assign(B=lambda d: -d.B).cumsum()

df.C.plot.area(stacked=False)
df.A.plot()
df.B.plot()

ymin, ymax = plt.ylim()

plt.ylim( [-ymax,ymax] )

plt.show()
```

In the above, we retrieve the axis range and then set the lower limit to match the upper limit.  You can elaborate on this in any way that seems appropriate.

Comment: I want the `ylim` to be dynamically set as it normally is.

Comment: Okay, do you want it to be always ymin = - ymax?   Or, what is the rule that you want the axis limits to follow?

Comment: I want it to behave in the way it normally does with ymin - 10% and ymax + 10%.  Roughly speaking.  I suspect my observation is a bug and I want a work around that isn't buggy.

Comment: I changed it to retrieve the limits and set ymin to -ymax.  You can elaborate on that any way that you want.  For example, find the max magnitude and use that instead.   Alternatively you can scan your data and set it as you wish.  What graphics engines do is choose "nice" values.